# can't load file in snapshot view... why?

Tags: clearcase

I get this error while I try to load a new snapshot view with my own config spec (this is base ClearCase).

> cleartool error: Unable to load "*filename.exe*": no version selected in configuration
>   specification.

- If I try to load a dynamic view with the **same** config spec - I can
  see this file (that can't be loaded). The selected version does exist on the config spec (of the snapshot view as well).
- If I change the config spec of the snapshot view (to default config spec) I can load all files with no problem (but on the other hand,   the missing file is not loaded since it's not part of the config       spec).

What goes wrong? Can you advice please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to debug this is to do a:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view/avob/parent/directory
cleartool ls

cd /path/to/dynamic/view/avob/parent/directory
cleartool ls
```

That allows to check:

- the status of the file in both views
- if the other files in that folder are selected with the same versions.